# unable to set id and name of second and thereafter cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem regarding setting id of cloned element.

first i have a partial view [mypartialview.cshtml] having a single element

```
@model mydata

@{
Layout = null;
}
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details,"","supp_int_mat_det")
```

now in my page i have a prototype

```
<div id="simtemplate" style="display: none">

    @Html.Partial("mypartialview", new mydata())

</div>
```

and i am writing this code in javascript click code

```
 function addsupp() {
    var component = "simtemplate";
    var idiv = $("#simtemplate").clone(); //.html();
    idiv.removeAttr("style");

    var newid = "CompetencyParts[" + counter + "]";
    counter = counter + 1;

    if (previd == "") {
        previd = newid;
    }
    var fdiv = idiv.find("#supp_int_mat_det");
    fdiv.addClass("ckeditor");
    fdiv.attr("name", newid);
    fdiv.attr("id", newid);

    $("#panel").append(idiv);

    var html = '';
    var config = { width: 400, height: 200 };
   // CKEDITOR.replace(newid);


}
```

i am successfull in setting id of the first cloned element
the second or thereafter cloned element have the ids same is the first element 
[image]
can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Could you please say where counter is set initially ?

Comment: at top of document                                               <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    var lessoncounter = 0;
    var previd = "";
</script>

Answer (score 0):

i got it.
actually i forgot to change the id of div.upon appending it becomes a duplicate of 'simtemplate' and later cloning attempts clones this duplicated div.since the duplicated div does not contain any original elements[the one found in simtemplate] so the id is not changed.
adding this line of code solved my problem.

```
var idiv = $("#lessonplan").clone(); //.html();
    idiv.removeAttr("style");

    var divid = "lessonplan" + getdivcount();

    idiv.attr("name", divid);
    idiv.attr("id", divid);
```